# Three bullets are shot in a sphere. What is the probabilty that all of them end up in the same hemisphere?

Tags: probability

Any ideas on how to solve it?

**EDIT**

The hemisphere is not predefined. It can be any hemisphere.

Comment: Is the hemisphere chosen ahead of time?

Comment: It depends a bit what  you do between the different shots. Typically in interviews, you are supposed to check with the interviewer and ask him/her to clarify. If you don't move the gun between the shots then I would guess the probability is 100%.

Comment: I have edited the question @Semiclassical

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure I'm visualizing it right, but if the hemisphere isn't chosen ahead of time (i.e. 'what is the probability that all three end up in 'some hemisphere') then I can hardly see how it wouldn't always be true.

Comment: What are your ideas ?

Comment: There is a difference between saying "Three bullets are shot *in* a sphere" and "Three bullets are shot *into* a sphere".

Comment: The question is very poorly worded. I think the notion was supposed to be that the three bullets landed in random spots within the sphere. Then the problem would be analogous to choosing three points randomly on the circumference of a circle. In that case the question is what is the probability that all three points are on the same semicircle.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1 because three points define a plane (P) that does not in general contain the origin (we set apart the cases where this plane contains the origin $0$, which is of probability 0). Then it suffices to consider the plane parallel to (P)  passing through the origin : it divides the sphere into two hemispheres, one of which contains the three points.

Answer (score 0):

It probably also depends on the way you choose (shoot at) those three points. Similarly to [Bertrand's paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bertrand_paradox_(probability)).

For example (referring back to @JeanMarie's answer), if you force the third bullet to make the plane of the three bullets go through the centre of the sphere, that certainly *is a* valid probability distribution. One might argue that's not random enough, but in any way that gives you a probability of zero.

Comment: In order to identify this as having "probability of zero" a probability distribution needs to be defined.  Forcing something (such as having the bullets travel in a common plane) that you say has probability zero then produces a *conditional* probability distribution (which must have total probability one, given the restricted circumstance).

Comment: I'm not sure if I get your point. By forcing I meant I could come up with a probability distribution which would produce such a result every time. E.g. putting a delta-function at the origin.

Comment: Actually, I just realised that we also have to agree on how to count those on the mid-plane (as in, is it a solid hemisphere with the boundaries or a hollow one)

Comment: Perhaps you are saying we should accept JeanMarie's Answer, given the limited information in the "interview" Question, with the rationale that either three bullets colinear with the center counts as being "in the same hemisphere" or amounts to an event of probability zero.